# Django CSRF Verification error using CBV and custom login page

Tags: python, django, cookies, forms-authentication, csrf

I'm having a 403 error when I try to login to my blog app of a django 1.8 project. The reason given is that the CSRF Cookie is not set. This happens approximately 80% of the time I try to login to the project in Chrome, while sometimes I am able to login to the edit view, but am then unable to update a post. I have tried setting the cookie with jQuery, in addition to adding the {% csrf_token %} tag in all of my post forms, and from my research would assume that using class based views automatically rendered the template with the relevant csrf information. I'm a bit at a loss at what I'm doing wrong, considering that it's not consistent about not working.

from blog.views.py:

```
class LoginView(FormView):
  success_url = '/blog/edit/'
  form_class = AuthenticationForm
  template_name = 'blog/login.html'
  @method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters('password'))
  @method_decorator(never_cache)
  @method_decorator(requires_csrf_token)
  def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  def form_valid(self, form):
    user = authenticate(username=self.request.POST['username'], password=self.request.POST['password'])
    if user:
      login(self.request, user)
    return super(LoginView, self).form_valid(form)

class LoggedIn(object):
  @method_decorator(requires_csrf_token)
  @method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/blog/login/'))
  def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(LoggedIn, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

class edit_view(LoggedIn, ListView):
  model = Post
  template_name = 'blog/edit_view.html'
  context_object_name = 'blog_posts'

class PostUpdate(LoggedIn, UpdateView):
  model = Post
  template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
  fields = ['title', 'author', 'body', 'categories']
  def get_object(self):
    slug = self.kwargs['postslug']
    return Post.objects.get(postslug=slug)
```

From blog.urls.py

```
url(r'^login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
url(r'^edit/(?P<postslug>[-\w\d]+)/$', views.PostUpdate.as_view(), name='update'),
```

For the html and js as it is rendered by the browser, I opened up my development instance at http://ec2-52-5-103-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8001/blog/login/ so that you can reproduce the error for yourself with the actual rendered templates.
I created a user: sample_user with password: password, for this purpose.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! I'm a noob at Django, Stack Overflow, and so much more, but would really love to follow best practices.

Headers for attempted login:

```
General:
  Remote Address:52.5.103.99:8001
  Request URL:http://ec2-52-5-103-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8001/blog/login/
  Request Method:POST
  Status Code:403 FORBIDDEN
Response Headers
  view source
  Content-Type:text/html
  Date:Thu, 23 Apr 2015 16:56:07 GMT
  Server:WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.9
  X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
Request Headers
  view source
  Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
  Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
  Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
  Cache-Control:no-cache
  Connection:keep-alive
  Content-Length:97
  Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  Cookie:IGFB={"user":{"name":"simplicedolce","id":"1193622126","count":"205"}}; csrftoken=5w6VuL8OpnTn676yhlGN5UCWI5h7gdE1
  Host:ec2-52-5-103-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8001
  Origin:http://ec2-52-5-103-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8001
  Pragma:no-cache
  Referer:http://ec2-52-5-103-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8001/blog/login/
  User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1)       AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36
Form Data
  view source
  view URL encoded
  csrfmiddlewaretoken:5w6VuL8OpnTn676yhlGN5UCWI5h7gdE1
  username:sample_user
  password:password
  next:
```

Comment: Any reason you are using `ensure_csrf_cookie` when you aren't making an ajax login call?

Comment: no, It was something I added experimentally in my troubleshooting, though it doesn't seem to be the root of the problem, upon testing its removal

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace along with the blog edit code?

Comment: I added the relevant view code, and also the Post update view, which has always not worked when a post modification has been tried. I'm working on getting a full stacktrace, I am not super familiar with django middleware, but it seems that with a little tinkering I can get it to print the full trace of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specifically add the tag to the form part of your template, class based views or not:

```
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```

Step 2 in the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/

Comment: The tag is in the form part of all of the templates. It does not seem to be the reason that the post is not working. Sorry if it was unclear in my question statement, I'll edit